# How do I set a environment variable from a powershell command?

Tags: command-line, powershell

I want to have a environment variable that contains the day of week in cmd.exe.

When I run this command I get the result I want.

```
C:\Users\tisc>powershell (get-date).dayofweek
Friday
```

Here I'm trying to store the result in a environment variable.

```
C:\Users\tisc>set dow = powershell (get-date).dayofweek
```

But when I try to get it I dont get the string as I wanted.

```
C:\Users\tisc>set dow
DoW=0
dow = powershell (get-date).dayofweek
```

My goal is to use the variable in a batch file for some backup scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it without a temp file you can do:

```
@ECHO off
FOR /F %%i in ('powershell.exe -noprofile "(get-date).DayOfWeek"') DO SET dow=%%i
ECHO Day of week %dow%
PAUSE
```

from the command prompt remove the double %%:

```
FOR /F %i in ('powershell.exe -noprofile "(get-date).DayOfWeek"') DO SET dow=%i
```

Using `-noprofile` will make it run faster if you have a profile set up for PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

```
powershell -noprofile -command {[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("dow", (get-date).DayofWeek, "User")}
```

Obviously you need to open other cmd to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can't do it directly, but you can use a temporary file to hold the result, and import it back into the variable:

```
@echo off
powershell (get-date).dayofweek > myTmpFile
set /p dow= < myTmpFile
del /q myTmpFile
echo %dow%
```